# How to update web.config files during upgrade?

Tags: asp.net, xml, deployment, web-config

For example:

1. The Administrator installs web application with version 1 of web.config, and sets a bunch of configuration settings.
2. New version of web application comes out, with changes to web.config.
3. The Administrator installs web application version 2, and now web.config version 1 is replaced with web.config version 2, and all settings in web.config version1 are lost.

The problem is obviously then that The Administrator must re-configure all the settings in web.config each time he installs a new version of the application.

How can I update the existing web.config (i.e. add new settings, security info, appSettings etc.) instead of replacing it? Basically, retain any settings that already exist, and add any new ones that arent there.

I am resorting to writing a basic application to compare the XML files, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why can't the developers provide a `web.config` that has the current settings to begin with?

Comment: My mistake if I made it sound like there is only one instance of the application. There are numerous installations at different sites running different settings, so your suggestion would require a separate setup for each site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of ASP.Net 2.0 you can use the Configuration API, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228060%28v=VS.80%29.aspx and http://odetocode.com/code/418.aspx

Another (related) option is to keep localised settings in external config files which would not be over-written when deploying a new version, see http://peterkellner.net/2008/02/23/webconfigbestpractice/

Comment: So I will have to code a little app to merge web.config files. I have been reading and it looks like XSLT might be an option, but I don't want to create a new XSLT file every time there is a new item in config, so writing an app to do the merging seems the easiest bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deployment system with templYou could templatize your web.config and use a deployment system such as kwateeSDCM that instantiates proper parameter values at deployment time based on the target server.